# Xcode 4.6.2 and strange iPhone Simulator issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I came across a strange iPhone simulator issue. I have created an application which uses MKMapView to show a map. I want this map to be centered and therefor used the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    location.latitude = 47.379022;
    location.longitude = 8.541001;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region.center = location;
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

This code works flawless in a fresh "HelloMap" Xcode project and does what it should - centering the map on Zurich.

But using the exact same code in another project puts the map to somewhere near the antarctica. I have already tried to clean the building environment by using "Product" -> "Clean"... no changes.

Also deleting the app from the emulated iPhone doesn't make a change. I also used the Terminal to check and remove any remaining apps from the corresponding folder.

It even seems that changes made to the Xcode project are not (always) getting transferred to the iPhone simulator. E.g the MKMapView even loads when the source code above is commented out...

I am running out of ideas here... any input?

[EDIT]

Resetting the whole simulator by going to "iOS-Simulator" -> "Inhalte und Einstellungen zurücksetzen" made it work once only (!!) ...

[EDIT]

This seems to be a runtime issue. Putting the code from above into "- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated" makes it to behave correctly - at least almost. The user now sees an animated fly from the "default location" to my coordinates.

Where do I need to put the code so the map is at the right position when the view is loaded?

Comment: Look at Debug->Location on iOS Simulator, it should be None, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Answer (score 0):

I was using viewWillAppear and had the same problem, use your suggestion with viewDidAppear and my problem was solve.